# How can i validate the UItext field for particular format?

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I am working on a application ,that has label and it display the duration of an event in format HH:MM:SS. Now i have to make it editable .so i am getting the values in text field.

**Is it possible to compare the changed value to validate in same format as well as in range of 23:59:59  ?**

**OR I use UIDatePicker to get the value **

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: use regex to validate

Comment: from user point of view best thing will be give an option to choose from UIDatePicker.  if you need code for that let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following :

```
NSString *dateFromTextfield = @"02:02:2015";

   // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM:dd:yyyy"];// here set format which you want...
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateFromTextfield];
```

and then checked

```
//set int position to 2 and 5  as it contain : for a valid date
unichar chr = [dateFromTextfield characterAtIndex:position];
NSLog(@"%c", chr);

if (chr == ':'){
      //valid date
    }
else{
      //not a valid date
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expression for validation of a perticular string. but for your issue you shoud use a date picker with date format of HH:MM:SS.  you can choose whatever option you like.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no code given is Questions so sharing the Idea to perform this specific task.

As About [UITextField](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) like A UITextField object is a control that displays editable text. And According to [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html).

The UITextFieldDelegate protocol defines the messages sent to a text field delegate as part of the sequence of editing its text.

All of the methods of this protocol are optional.

You can use

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

meanly the delegate is called if the specified text should be changed.SO as user enter text character by character you can validate text as per the requirement ([As in iOS you can validate String using the regular expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

As if you want to learn more about these kind of delegate functions hit given links.

And if you just looking only for the way to get the date from user then [UIDatePicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html). is very nice way provided by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSDateFormatter for Converting string into Date.if you don't conform to formate nsdateformatter will return nil value.

```
     NSString *dateForTest=@"12:15:36";
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[NSDateFormatter new];
     [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
     NSDate *date=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateForTest];
```

Check here you are getting nil or a date value?